# Familiar with TeXCeL?

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors, typography

Our journal publisher has advised us it is evaluating TexCeL for typesetting, following many problems with math, and typography in general, in our proofs. I can find no technical details about it online.

If you are familiar with or know of TeXCeL, I would appreciate if you could point me in the direction of where I may be able to get some technical details about it (not available from publisher as of yet). I have read the article from the 2015 TUG conference. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this is close to the "opinion based" close reason but if anyone wonders what you mean I guess you mean https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-2/tb116garcia.pdf

Comment: What typesetting software/method is your publisher using now?

Comment: @Kim Using TeXcel for journal publishing seems like a rather odd approach. Are you sure that they didn't mean XeTeX?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes, they said Texcel. I agree with you. 

With the (lack of) info I found online (only the TUG article), I have become even more concerned. We've requested specifics from the publisher, so we'll see what they come back with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton They use something they developed in house. Our publisher is Wiley.